# How to make one mesh from several meshes without joining them (without CTRL+J, keeping boolean modifiers)

Tags: modifiers, unity

I am learning blender for 2 days.

I have a low poly model that has certain meshes and materials assigned to them (the materials are just different colors). I have boolean modifiers on some meshes. I don't apply booleans because I might need to change the mesh that is subtracted from my main mesh (to keep the main mesh vertices).

For optimization, I need to make 1 mesh from all parts. But when I select all parts and press CTRL+J, all booleans and materials break. I was going to make 1 material for mesh like in this video: youtube.com/watch?v=3IQxb71Sl-w
but what to do with booleans? Every time Shift+D?

How to make 1 mesh from parts and be able to change objects, not vertices (as everyone shows in tutorial videos)

p.s. I will be using the model in Unity along with the SkinnedMeshRenderer

Comment: If your goal is to use the model in Unity and intend to optimize it, the usual workflow is to create a high poly mesh first and then create a low poly mesh which approximates the shape of the high poly. You can then bake textures such as the normal map, which will help to make the low poly model seem like it has far more geometric details than it actually has.

Comment: As for optimization in Blender, you might be able to join objects that are used for the same purpose, e.g. those that will be subtracted from another object. However, if you are already running into performance problem this might not help. You would rather have to reduce the complexity of your geometry.